# ElasticSearch - Can I use the join data type for many to one relationship cases (sql like)?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, I need to keep one to many relationship and have been thinking about [Join Data Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#:%7E:text=The%20join%20data%20type%20is,name%20and%20a%20child%20name.). I know that denormalized documents are preferred and the way to go, however in my case the synchronization logic is not straighforward. My case is as follows:

1. Parent is updated on a daily bases.
2. Parent documents are lesser than child documents. One parent document can have up to 100.000 child documents.
3. Child documents keep being added on a daily basis.

My index have about 20 million documents and 120 Gb.

Is it advisable to use [Join data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#:%7E:text=The%20join%20data%20type%20is,name%20and%20a%20child%20name.) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommndate to use as mentined in [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#parent-join):

> We don’t recommend using multiple levels of relations to replicate a
> relational model. Each level of relation adds an overhead at query
> time in terms of memory and computation. For better search
> performance, denormalize your data instead.

Also, your parent and child documents should be in same shards and you need to use `routing` while indexing document in Elasticsearch.

> It is required to index the lineage of a parent in the same shard so
> you must always route child documents using their greater parent id.

There are other limitation as well which is listed [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_restrictions).

I will suggest to do POC with your data and check performance and if performance is as per your expectation then you can go ahead with Join data type.